# How to peek/read/display VS Code's special ${variables}?

Tags: visual-studio-code, variables

There are values like `${workspaceFolder}` and commands like `${command:vscode-embedded.st.gdb}` in workspace JSON files like tasks.json, launch.json, etc. I want to know what they translate to, so I'd like to know if there is a way to peek and search somehow for the variables root path in VS Code.

Is there a simple way to do it?

I tried looking for it in VS Code's search box with +Ctrl+P+ and entering `"@ ${workspaceFolder}"` but it doesn't seem to give any relevant results.

Comment: the value of the variables is well defined, what do you want to do with this